# How to update a row in the text box to the datagridview in vb net that also update the MySQL xampp

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Every time I run my program and click update it always says 'update failed'
i want to  update a row in the text box  that shows in the datagridview in visual basic net that also update/show the MySQL xampp
How do I solve this problem in the code?

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Menu

```
Dim dr As MySqlDataReader

Private Sub Menu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Connection()
    LoadRecords()

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
        If PnameTb.Text = String.Empty Or PTb.Text = String.Empty Then
            MsgBox("Please enter information", vbCritical)
            Return
        End If
        If CatCb.Text = String.Empty Or QtyTb.Text = String.Empty Then
            MsgBox("Please enter information", vbCritical)
            Return
        End If

        If MsgBox("Add this product?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
            cn.Open()
            cm = New MySqlCommand("insert into product (product_name,product_description,product_quantity,product_unit,product_price)values(@product_name,@product_description,@product_quantity,@product_unit,@product_price)", cn)
            With cm.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@product_name", PnameTb.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@product_description", CatCb.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@product_quantity", QtyTb.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@product_unit", UTb.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@product_price", PTb.Text)
            End With
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn.Close()
            MsgBox("Product has been successfully added!", vbInformation)
            LoadRecords()
            Clear()

        End If

        PnameTb.Text = ""
        CatCb.Text = ""
        QtyTb.Text = ""
        UTb.Text = ""
        PTb.Text = ""
    Catch ex As Exception
        cn.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub PTb_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PTb.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub PTb_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles PTb.KeyPress
    Select Case Asc(e.KeyChar)
        Case 48 To 57
        Case 46
        Case 8
        Case Else
            e.Handled = True
    End Select
End Sub

Sub LoadRecords()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    Dim i As Integer
    cn.Open()
    cm = New MySqlCommand("select * from product", cn)
    dr = cm.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        i += 1
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, dr.Item("product_name").ToString, dr.Item("product_description").ToString, dr.Item("product_quantity").ToString, dr.Item("product_unit").ToString, dr.Item("product_price").ToString)
    End While
    dr.Close()
    cn.Close()

End Sub
Private Sub Clear()
    PnameTb.Text = ""
    CatCb.Text = ""
    QtyTb.Text = ""
    UTb.Text = ""
    PTb.Text = ""
End Sub
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    ' Adjust the index or column name for product_id
    IdTb.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
    PnameTb.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
    CatCb.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
    QtyTb.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
    UTb.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value
    PTb.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value
End Sub

Sub Edit()
    Dim i As Integer
    Try
        cn.Open()
        Dim cm As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE `product` SET `product_name`= @product_name, `product_description`= @product_description,`product_quantity`= @product_quantity,`product_unit`= @product_unit,`product_price`= @product_price WHERE `product_id`= @product_id", cn)
        cm.Parameters.Clear()
        ' Use product_id from the TextBox
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_id", IdTb.Text)
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_name", PnameTb.Text)
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_description", CatCb.Text)
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_quantity", QtyTb.Text)
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_unit", UTb.Text)
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_price", PTb.Text)


        i = cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If i > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Product has been updated successfully!", "grocery_store", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Product update failed!", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error updating product:", ex.Message)
    Finally
        cn.Close()
    End Try
    Clear()
    LoadRecords()
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Edit()

End Sub
```

End Class

It always says update failed.

Comment: You're taking something simple and making it unnecessarily complex. Use a data adapter. Call Fill to populate a DataTable and bind that to the grid via a BindingSource. Bind the BindingSource to your individual controls too. After making changes, call Update to save.